# Why is the origin the only zero of this class of functions in the unit disk?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let f be analytic in $\mathbb{D}, f(0) = 0, f'(0) = 1$ and assume that $Re(\frac{zf'(z)}{f(z)}) > 0$. Then f has a simple zero at the origin and no other zeros in the unit disk. Why?

Comment: For which $z \in \mathbb D$ is $Re(\frac{zf'(z)}{f(z)}) > 0$ valid ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\frac{f'}{f}$ has a pole of order one at every zero of $f$, so $g(z):=z\frac{f'}{f}$ has a simple pole at every zero of $f$ different from $0$. Near a zero ($\neq 0$) of $f$, $g$ can be written as $\frac c{z-z_0}+\psi(z)$, where $\psi$ is holomorphic in a neighbourhood of $z_0$. It is easy to see that for every value of $c\in\mathbb{C}-\{0\}$, $g(z_0-c\varepsilon)=-\frac{1}{\varepsilon}+\psi(z_0-c\varepsilon)$. Taking $\varepsilon>0$ small enough, we get that $\Re(g(z_0-c\varepsilon))<0$, contradicting the requirement. Thus $f$ cannot have any zero on $\mathbb{D}-\{0\}$.